# I am using Bootstrap 4 carousel. Its working on all windows and android OS, but its not working on Mac and Iphone OS. any solution for this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using the Bootstrap 4 carousel. It's working on all windows and android OS, but it's not working on Mac and iPhone OS. any solution for this? here is my code
github.com/saivamsi07/bootstrap/blob/master/carousel

Comment: Define 'not working' ? Also, add your markup here, or even as a snippet. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Think this could help with your problem: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14973

Not sure how I can help more without seeing the code.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The code is provided in the link:  https://github.com/saivamsi07/bootstrap/blob/master/carousel